# Pdflatex fails when using datetime package

Tags: errors, datetime, datetime2

I have been debugging a class that uses the `datetime` package. It seems the offending statement is a `\RequirePackage{datetime}`.

It seems that including the `datetime` package is causing pdflatex to fail. I have created a minimum *non* working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{datetime}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

When I build this with pdflatex no pdf file is created and the log file is empty. When I run pdflatex testfile in the terminal I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:\Users\martin\Desktop\Temp\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\datetime\datetime.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"))
```

Then pdflatex crashes.  using latex testfile and xelatex testfile also crash at the same point. lualatex doesn't crash but only gets to the same point and doesn't output anything.

I am aware that the `datetime`  pack­age is ob­so­lete and has been replaced by `date­time2`. However, the same problem occurs when using `datetime2`.

datetime and datetime2 are installed and in the appropriate locations. I have refreshed FNDB as well.

Any ideas on why this is happening/how to resolve this?

Comment: it runs with no error here what error do you get do you have datetime installed? please show the full log from that test file (if you get no log, show the terminal output)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I don't get an error message. Just nothing happens. Log file is empty. If I comment out the \usepackage{datetime} line everything works fine.

Comment: on the commandline type `pdflatex testfile` (if that is testfile.tex) and show the terminal output if (for some strange reason) you get no log.

Comment: "log" means the file with extension `.log` that the TeX compilers automatically create, not the more or less broken "log" in some window of TeX IDE's.

Comment: When I run pdflatex testfile I get the normal looking info until the line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MikTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty. Then pdflatex crashes.

Comment: Package `datetime` is installed (`kpsewhich datetime.sty`)?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek. it is installed in ...tex/latex/datetime/datetime.sty. Similarily datetime2 is installed.

Comment: Post the terminal output as suggested by David. Also, compare with other TeX compilers (`latex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`). What's the version of pdfTeX (`pdftex --version`)?

Comment: Updated the question with the command line output. latex testfile and xelatex testfile also crash at the same point. lualatex doesn't crash but also doesn't output anything.

Comment: Make sure, that all needed packages are installed, see `\RequirePackage` calls in `datetime.sty`. Not shown in the log are `fmtcount`, `ifthen`, `datetime-defaults`.

Comment: To narrow the problematic code down, copy `datetime.sty` into the working directory. Then `\endinput` ends the reading of the file. Put it to the last known working position, right after `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}`, test and move `\endinput` further to the end until you find the problematic code section.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek. Turns out fmtcount was missing. Installing it seems to have resolved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that `LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>` means that you have a very old installation... I suggest updating MiKTeX through its Update Wizard!!!

Answer (score 5):

In comments you indicated `fntcount` was not available. If so the terminal output would be

```
$ pdflatex pp070
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pp070.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.11> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime/datetime.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `fmtcount.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

If you didn't get that message then you were presumably running in  nonstopmode

```
$ pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode pp070
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pp070.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.11> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime/datetime.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `fmtcount.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.45 \@ifundefined
                  {@FCmodulo}%^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on pp070.log.
```

or batchmode

```
$ pdflatex -interaction=batchmode pp070
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

But even in batch mode, where the terminal output is suppressed the log file will show the cause of the problem

it ends:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `fmtcount.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.45 \@ifundefined
                  {@FCmodulo}%^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

Comment: OP also reported a problem with `datetime2` which doesn't require `fmtcount` so I suspect there are other packages missing (such as `tracklang`, which is required by `datetime2` but not `datetime`).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot quite probalby but main problem is (a) hiding the error messages and (b) not checking the log were the hidden messages are hiding.